# How to show water mark in asp.net without using ajax toolkit control?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I want to show water mark on a text field but i dont want to use ajax toolkit

Comment: I have a very small web site but ajax toolkit is a little bit heavy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Enter first name">
```

Comment: works with only HTML5 complatible browsers and may not work with IE

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    var defaultText = "Enter your text here";
    function WaterMark(txt, evt)
    {
        if(txt.value.length == 0 && evt.type == "blur")
        {
            txt.style.color = "gray";
            txt.value = defaultText;
        }
        if(txt.value == defaultText && evt.type == "focus")
        {
            txt.style.color = "black";
            txt.value="";
        }
    }
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txt_Name" runat="server" Text = "Enter your Name here"
    ForeColor = "Gray" onblur = "WaterMark(this, event);"
    onfocus = "WaterMark(this, event);">
</asp:TextBox>
```

or simply do like this

```
<input name="q" onfocus="if (this.value=='search') this.value = ''" type="text" value="search">
```

You could also add the onblur event to check: if (this.value=='') this.value = 'search'

This would re-print the watermark when the user clicks outside the textbox and the field is empty.

this might helps you.